# Cassandra: how to you include the query with the results?

Tags: cassandra

I run a Cassandra command:

```
cqlsh> capture 'out.txt';
cqlsh> select * from account;
cqlsh> exit;
```

but how can I get 'select * from account' to appear with the results ... so I can correlate the results to the command? I have 20 or 30 selects I'd like to debug this way. Seems weirdly hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible via the command. 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCapture.html

You could do something like

> bash> echo 'command 1' >> out.txt

```
cqlsh> capture 'out.txt';
cqlsh> select * from account;
cqlsh> exit;
```